# How to make calling a method dynamic with a Switch Case- Java

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, switch-statement

I want to call a method. Depending on a argument a certain method will be called.
Currently I am trying to achieve this using a Switch Case, but I cant get it to work.

Code:

```
String getoption = null;
switch (rateIndex){

case 3:
    getoption = "bar.getOneMonth();"
case 4:
    getoption = "bar.getTwoMonth();"
case 5:
    getoption = "bar.getThreeMonth();"

}

Big Decimal qMidRate = null;

for(MonthlyRates bar: results){
    qMidRate = getoption;  
    //more logic 
}
```

I am trying to get a Big Decimal value from the get methods, is there any way of doing this? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If all those methods are returning strings, simply ditch the double quotes:

```
case 3:
    getoption = bar.getOneMonth();
    break;
case 4:
    getoption = bar.getTwoMonth();
    break;
case 5:
    getoption = bar.getThreeMonth();
    break;
```

Comment: assuming I would put it inside the for loop?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with method references/lambdas if you're using java 8.  Something like:

```java
    // I have no idea what 'getOneMonth', etc. are returning or have as parameters...
    // This assumes they take a Long, and return a String, 'cause I don't know.
    Function<Long, String> choice = null;
    switch (rateIndex) {
        case 3:
            choice = bar::getOneMonth;
            break;
        case 4:
            choice = bar::getTwoMonths;
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            throw new HissyFit();
    }

    for (final MonthlyRates rates : bar.getMonthlyRates()) {
        final String methodCallResult = choice.apply(rates.getSomeLong());
    }
```

Comment: the get methods dont have any parameters and return a Big Decimal.

Comment: `Supplier<BigDecimal>` would work then.  But if you only need to call them once, like the other answer says, you can just store the result as a `BigDecimal` somewhere and use that.